# Windows Phone 8.1 phone parameter data on backward navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.1 App.

There are some screens on my app. On the first screen, I am navigate my screen to second screen with a parameter data. now i want to navigate to first screen from second screen with different parameter data.

Using `Frame.Navigate(typeof(frame1),parameter);` I can pass data from first screen to second screen (forward navigation)

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(frame1), "data");
```

but how can I pass data from second screen to first screen (backward navigation) ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution. Using the `Frame.GoBack` method you cannot pass a parameter. Furthermore if you use `NavigationHelper.GoBack` you cannot pass a parameter neither. This is by desing. If you go back, you will open the view that was previous open. That is the definition of `going back`. You want to "restore" a previous state.

But there would be a possible solution, when you store your new data into a variable that you can access from `frame1`.

Can you state why you would use a different data for backwards navigation?

Another, better possibility is to use a `ContentDialog`. There you can add your desired ViewModel to the DataContext prior opening. After that the ContentDialog is closed you can validate the data passed to it.

```
ContentDialog cd = new MyContentDialog();

if (parameter != null)
{
    cd.DataContext = // set context here;
}
await cd.ShowAsync();
//now lets validate or process the necessary data.
```

Comment: i want a confirmation page from main page. user save main page, control passes to confirm page where user ask a input value. This input value pass need to be pass back to main page.. i now this is possible with popup but we want a new page instead of popup.. also i need to maintain back button flow

Comment: Do you mean with `popup` opening a ContentDialog?

Comment: Requirement is to create a new page  instead of popup

Comment: Then I would suggest you to store the necessary details into a global variable and read it when you navigate back to the previous view.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is to declare a global variable in `App.xaml.cs` so that you can access it from Frame2 and set a value, then you get the value from Frame1.

```
public static Object navigationData
{
      get;
      set;
 }
```

And from everywhere you access it using

```
var data = App.navigationData;
```